# Referencing a string inside an NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, nsurl

I'm trying to use this string inside this NSURL however I don't think its right and in turn giving me an ASI HTTP request failed error.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com/places/%@/reviews.xml",self.identifier]];
```

Comment: If self.identifier is a NSString, your code is correct. The problem must be somewhere else: can you provide more code? What is self.identifier for you? Did you try to NSLog the value of url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.identifier` returns (in most cases) an object of the type `id`. You cannot cast this object to a `NSString*`.

The only exception is the in 10.7 newly introduced `identifier` property of `NSString*` in the `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification` protocol.

Can you elaborate your question so we can see what type `self` has?

Comment: identifier is just a string that I holds a place id. It passes the string from one view to another. self.identifier is a string I simply want cast it inside the URL.

Comment: As notme already said the problem will be somewhere else. Are you sure, self.identifier actually contains something and are you sure that the domain `https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com/places/{{ self.identifier goes here}}/reviews.xml` exists and is reachable?