# ASI HTTP Request for posting a review

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, asihttprequest

In my app I am sending a ASI HTTP post request so I user can post a review to my web service however I'm having some trouble sending the request it always seems to be failing I'm sure its a simple error I'm over looking but its driving me made.

My Create Review Class is as follows:

```
-(void)Submit
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com/places/%@/reviews.xml",self.identifier]];


    //[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com///places/%@/reviews.xml",self.identifier]];


    self.bestnight.text = @"Monday";
    ASIFormDataRequest *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request1 setUsername:self.username];
    [request1 setPassword:self.password];

    [request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


    [request1 setPostValue:self.bestnight.text forKey:@"review[best-night]"];
    [request1 setPostValue:self.comments.text forKey:@"review[comments]"];
    [request1 setPostValue:self.rating.text forKey:@"review[rating]"];

    [request1 setDelegate:self];
    [request1 startAsynchronous];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"FINISH Response received: %@", [request responseString]);

    UIAlertView * av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank You" message:@"Your review was successfully posted. Thank You for making our App Better." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];

    [av show];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"FAILED Response received: %@", [request responseString]);


}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving from your webserver ?

Comment: This is a duplicated question! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114599/referencing-a-string-inside-an-nsurl

Comment: 2011-11-13 22:20:52.475 ClubsNi[14936:ec03] FAILED Response received: HTTP Digest: Access denied.

Comment: didn't think it was failing for the other reason. Thats why I created another question. Thanks

Comment: It's a server problem. Check your login/password. And I see your URL is HTTPS, so disable certificate validation by adding `[request1 setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:NO];
```

Or if that doesn't work, try calling the same but passing 'YES'. Also as others have said double check your username/password.